# Do Kohanim fast on Yom Kippur in the Bet Hamikdash?

Tags: beis-hamikdash

Do Kohanim fast on Yom Kippur in the Bet Hamikdash? 
I'm doubting it because I know that on this day they should sacrifice offerings, and as far as I know they should eat from it too.

Also according to Rambam (Taanit 3;2) they have a privilege in the community fasting because they work there and they need to have some energy for doing their job properly.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but which offerings on YK would need eating?

Comment: @AKA the chatat of the musaf in pinchas

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They would fast and would eat whatever sacrifices needed eating the following night (11 Tishrei) after the fast ended. We know this because the Mishna (Menachot 11:7) discusses how they would eat it that night if that night was Shabbat and cooking was forbidden.

Answer (score 6):

There is one person that had a heter to eat if need be and that was the m'shaleiach of the Seir Azazel.  There was 10 sukkos set up along the way to azazel and had food and drink prepared if the sender got weak and needed. According to the Ohr Sameach on the Rambam Erev Yom Hakippurim 3:7 held this applies even not in a case of sakanas nefashos. However the Tosfos Yeshanim hold only when sakanas nefashos.

At the end of the day the gemara (Yoma 67) says this never happened that the sender accepted the food.